# Как воткнуть картинку любого размера в div, чтобы она не вылезала за его края

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
    .span11{
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        margin-left: 1px;
     } 
    .span11 img{
        max-width:  100%;
        height: auto;
     }
    .wr{
        width:303px; 
     }
</style>

         <div class="wr">
                <div class="span11">                
                    <a href="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg"><img src="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg" alt=""></a>                    
                </div>
                <div class="span11">
                    <a href="https://f.vividscreen.info/soft/66d0826256cf1c80b823ae39c38b36a9/Manhattan-Bridge-New-York-City-wide-l.jpg"><img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/big7/194/USA_Skyscrapers_Boston_466431.jpg" alt=""></a>                   
                </div>  
                <div class="span11">            
                    <a href="https://i.imgpile.com/2e15654b28e456cb505d2936902e7772.md.jpg"><img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/big3/803/374490-svetik.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1zm997dc/8/

Уточняю: чтобы все img были выровнены  и упакованы в div class="wr" вне зависимости от размера картинки. Все картинки должны быть равны по ширине и по высоте между собой и точно помещаться в контейнер wr

Comment: А вы указали, что изображения должны быть выровнены? а как? по горизонтали или по вертикали, или может по горизонтали и вертикали?

Comment: Как насчёт `overflow-x: hidden ` для нужного `div`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zm997dc/12/

Comment: первая картинка вертикальная и все время вылезает за пределы нижнего края. Чего только не пробовал. Ну не резать же ее под размер

Comment: А скрипты юзать не хочется?

Comment: хочется принципиально разобраться в этой ситуации с помощью CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `flexbox`
https://jsfiddle.net/1zm997dc/13/

```css
.span11{
 } 
.span11 img{
  max-width:  100%;
  height: auto;
}
.wr{
  width:500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
     <div class="span11">    
      <a href="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg"><img src="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg" alt=""></a>     
     </div>
     <div class="span11">
      <a href="https://f.vividscreen.info/soft/66d0826256cf1c80b823ae39c38b36a9/Manhattan-Bridge-New-York-City-wide-l.jpg"><img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/big7/194/USA_Skyscrapers_Boston_466431.jpg" alt=""></a>     
     </div> 
     <div class="span11">   
      <a href="https://i.imgpile.com/2e15654b28e456cb505d2936902e7772.md.jpg"><img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/big3/803/374490-svetik.jpg" alt=""></a>
     </div>
          <div class="span11">    
      <a href="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg"><img src="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg" alt=""></a>     
     </div>
   </div>
```

Поправка...
ДУБЛЬ 2 - https://jsfiddle.net/1zm997dc/14/

```css
.span11{
 } 
.span11 img{
  height: 100px;
}
.wr{
  width:500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
     <div class="span11">    
      <a href="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg"><img src="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg" alt=""></a>     
     </div>
     <div class="span11">
      <a href="https://f.vividscreen.info/soft/66d0826256cf1c80b823ae39c38b36a9/Manhattan-Bridge-New-York-City-wide-l.jpg"><img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/big7/194/USA_Skyscrapers_Boston_466431.jpg" alt=""></a>     
     </div> 
     <div class="span11">   
      <a href="https://i.imgpile.com/2e15654b28e456cb505d2936902e7772.md.jpg"><img src="http://s1.1zoom.me/big3/803/374490-svetik.jpg" alt=""></a>
     </div>
          <div class="span11">    
      <a href="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg"><img src="http://www.bgpics.ru/pictures/1536x2048/2043-leto-1536x2048.jpg" alt=""></a>     
     </div>
   </div>
```

**clearfix**

```
.cfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Класс `cfix` нужно добавлять к родительскому блоку.

Comment: так они же повылазили еще хуже по высоте

Comment: @Proshka, исправил))) так?)

Comment: Круто! Это хорошее решение. А как без flex? Можно придумать? Хочется разобраться в принципе, почему такое происходит. Ведь картинка при указанных свойствах ОБЯЗАНА сидеть внутри div

Comment: @Proshka, только если использовать скрипты. но в защиту `flexbox` хочу сказать, что его поддерживает 97.68% браузеров юзверов... https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @Proshka, а почему картинки вылазят за див? дело в том, что флоат работает со своей спецификой. и его нужно отключать (сбрасывать, обнулять и т.д.) можно для этого использовать `clearfix` для родительского блока) сейчас в ответ добавлю)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zm997dc/25/

Comment: @Proshka, они из блока `<div class="wr">` не вылазят)))

Comment: я неправильно выразил мысль: первое изображение, как и остальные находятся в родительском блоке, но первое изображение растягивает род блок. Так вот и вопрос: как их устаканить в один размер и поместить друг за другом? Прекрасно получилось с flex. Если добавить фиксированную высоту род блоку - они попросту вылазят за его пределы

Comment: @Proshka, фишка в том, что их нужно выравнивать либо по горизонтали, либо по вертикали... иначе изображения будут растянутыми и некрасивыми... в данном случае по вертикали нужно выравнивать, и корректировать расстояние между ними (если это не `flexbox`, там оно может автоматически регулироваться), но в любом случае нужно вычислять размер высоты программно, пример: https://jsfiddle.net/1zm997dc/28/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!